Proving a linear operator equation
Let T be a linear operator in finite dimensional inner product space such that $T^2 = \frac{1}{2}(T + T^*)$, then show that $T^2 = T$ and T is normal , i.e  , $T^*T=TT^* $ .Having a hard time proving this fact.
A few things I know are that:

$T^2$ is self-adjoint and all eigenvalues are real
$T^2$ is Unitarily diagonalizable and in that case $D = P^{-1}T^2P = P^{-1}TP P^{-1}TP$
I am aware that $T^2$ eigenvalues are exactly the eigenvalues of T squared, but we have not learned this fact yet (relies on Jordan form, coming in the future..)

How can I use this to answer??

Posts don't begin at the title. Please put the entire question in the body of the post.

$$T^2 + T^\ast T = 2 \cdot \frac{1}{2}(T + T^\ast)T = 2T^3 = 2T \cdot \frac{1}{2}(T + T^\ast) = T^2 + TT^\ast$$
So $T^\ast T = TT^\ast$, i.e., $T$ is normal.
Now, by spectral theorem, we may unitarily diagonalize $T$. Then $T^2 = \frac{1}{2}(T + T^\ast)$ implies $\lambda^2 = \frac{1}{2}(\lambda + \bar{\lambda})$ for any eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $T$. Solving the equation yields $\lambda = 0, 1$, both of which satisfy $\lambda^2 = \lambda$. Thus, $T^2 = T$.

Brilliant.. thank you!

The result is true in any finite or infinite dimensional inner product space, provided that $T$ has an adjoint. The notions of eigenvalues or diagonalisation are irrelevant.
By the given condition, $T^\ast=2T^2-T$ is a polynomial in $T$. Hence it commutes with $T$, meaning that $T$ is normal.
Let $A=\frac12(T+T^\ast)$ and $B= \frac{1}{2i}(T-T^\ast)$. By construction, both operators are Hermitian. They also commute, because $T$ is normal. Now, from $T^2=\frac12(T+T^\ast)$, we obtain $(A+iB)^2=A$ and in turn $A^2-B^2+i(AB+BA)=A$. By comparing the Hermitian and skew-Hermitian parts on both sides, we get
\begin{align}
&A^2-B^2=A,\tag{1}\\
&AB=-BA.\tag{2}
\end{align}
However, as we have observed earlier, $A$ and $B$ commute. Therefore  $(2)$ implies that $AB=0$. It follows that
$$
B^3=-A(AB)+B^3=-(A^2-B^2)B
\stackrel{\text{by }(1)}{=}-AB=0.
$$
Since $B$ is Hermitian,
$$
B^3=0
\implies B^4=0
\implies (B^2)^\ast B^2=0
\implies B^2=0
\implies B^\ast B=0
\implies B=0
\implies T=T^\ast.
$$
Hence $T$ is Hermitian and from $T^2=\frac12(T+T^\ast)$, we obtain $T^2=T$.
